# Card.io Does not scan non - Raised Digit Credit Cards

Tags: android, ios, credit-card, card.io

I have a problem with scanning non-raised digit credit cards with card.io sdk. I haven't seen any explanation about this issue on the official site of card.io. Does this sdk work for only raised digit credit cards?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jeff here from card.io.  In short, yes, the sdk only works for raised digit credit cards.  Scanning cards on a mobile device is hard, and the team chose to start by scanning the largest percentage of cards on the market, and do it well.  There are plans to support more cards and card types in the future. For now, please know that the sdk doesn't scan everything.  Hope that helps!

Comment: I suggest working toward scanning of flat cards. More card companies will move this way in the future as they withstand wear and tear better. Discover in specific has moved to this method completely with the Discover IT card.

Comment: @Jeff Brateman : is this issues still there? I'm facing the same.

Comment: Yes, card.io has not improved its scanning functionality as of yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to the card not having embossed numbers, or not a pattern that they support. See the Issue tracker of cardIO for more info. [cardIO Issue](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK/issues/55)